# Spirit Airlines online check-in with no printer

Tags: air-travel, check-in, spirit-airlines

Can I just check in online and then print boarding passes from the kiosk at the airport? I am on vacation and don't have a printer available to me to print out anything.

Comment: If you're staying in a hotel, most of them have a "business center" where you can print your boarding pass. Some actually have dedicated stations specifically designated as "boarding pass printing workstations". Ask reception or the concierge.